# How can i make this code more compact and easier to implement?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a way of searching for books in a csvfile based on data that the user provides. If they don't provide any data for a certain input such as genre, then all genres of books are used. for example if i entered: Author: - , Bookname: - , genre: Sci-Fi, then all Sci-Fi books are given, regardless of author or title.

```
def filltreeview(self , authorvar , booknamevar , genrevar):
    author = authorvar.get()
    bookname = booknamevar.get()
    genre = genrevar.get()
    books = []

    if genre == 'Genre':
        if author == '':
            if bookname == '':
                msg.showerror('Error' , 'Please specify some details')
            else:
                with open('Books.txt' , 'r') as csvfile:
                    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                    for row in reader:
                        if row == []:
                            pass
                        elif row[2] == bookname:
                            books.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]])


        else:
            with open('Books.txt' , 'r') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)    
                for row in reader:
                    if row == []:
                        pass
                    elif row[1] == author:
                        books.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]])
                print(books)
                if bookname == '':
                    pass
                else:
                    for i in books:
                        if i[2] != bookname:
                            books.remove(i)


    else:
        with open('Books.txt' , 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if row == []:
                    pass
                elif row[3] == genre:
                    books.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]])
                    print(books)

                    if author == '':
                        if bookname == '':
                            pass
                    else:
                        for i in books:
                            if i[1] != author:
                                books.remove(i)
                                print(books)

                    if bookname == '':
                        pass
                    else:
                        for i in books:
                            if i[2] != bookname:
                                books.remove(i)
                                print(books)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def get_all_books(reader_path):
    books = []
    with open(reader_path , 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            books.append(row[:4])
    return books

def remove_books(books, row_num, value):
    for book in books:
        if book[row_num] is not value:
            books.remove(book)
    return books

def filltreeview(self , authorvar , booknamevar , genrevar):
    author, bookname, genre = authorvar.get(), booknamevar.get(), genrevar.get()
    if genre == 'Genre' and not author and not bookname:
        msg.showerror('Error' , 'Please specify some details')
        # a return here will avoid adding the rest of the code under 'else'
    else:
        books = get_all_books('Books.txt')
        if genre:
            books = remove_books(books, 3, genre)
        if author:
            books = remove_books(books, 1, author)
        if bookname:
            books = remove_books(books, 2, bookname)
        print(books)
```

Comment: This worked apart from the remove books part, to fix it i created a list comprehension to store only the things i wanted to keep and returned that(still called books) this solved the problem. Not sure what the problem with the remove was but it whenever i printed book at the start of the for loop it only printed books[0] and books[2].

Comment: Glad I could help, if you found the answer useful please accept it. 

The remove code worked for a little test set I had created, I shall look into more examples and see where it failed and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions May help you here, for instance this chunk of code:

```
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                    if row == []:
                        pass
                    elif row[i] == bookname:
                        books.append([row[x],row[y],row[z],row[w]])
```

Seems to be written multiple times, so you may extract it into separate function and then you can reuse it. Remember a function should do only one thing, so it can be reused with different scenarios and usecases.

Also you should have alook on [`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). This function should be used when you are trying to accomplish a thing, but you will do it differently based on the type of you parameter.